# Problem: Any logged-in user can access Django Admin panel

Tags: django

I have my account with `is_superuser = 1` and other users with `is_superuser = 0` and `is_staff = 0`. But Django does not restrict access to "not-staff" users.
So, any logged-in user can access admin panel.

From Django documentation:

> By default, logging in to the admin requires that the user has the is_superuser or is_staff attribute set to True.

But this does not work. I do not have any changes in admin settings. Except custom admin panel URL:

```
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    path('my-admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So where can be the problem with not working Django restrictions?

Django==2.2.4

Database: MySQL

Comment: Why are you even using a custom admin user database.

Comment: @Moha369 what do you mean? Did not understand you. I did not customize the Admin panel.

Comment: If you are not customizing then that should be not happening, anyway we are here to solve a problem, how are you creating the users ? Using a form or manually ?

Comment: @Moha369 users in MySQL database were created by importing data from SQLite. This was because I chenged the database for my project from SQLite to MySQL. I do not know if the problem with not working restrictions to Admin was before switching to MySQL or not. 
Maybe the problem is because of MySQL could create different column types. I am checking now all column types to make sure that they are all right for Django. For example. that is_staff = 0 (not is_staff is null) etc.

Comment: I asked how are you creating the users, not where are you storing the users, what i want you to tell me how are the users created ? With a form they fill or you manually do them ? And Maybe Maybe The SQLite-MySQL is the problem which is unlikely IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because in MySQL database `field_type` for `is_superuser` was `Text`. I changed the field type to `TINYINT(1)` (boolean type) and now Django does not allow all users to access Admin (except superuser).

**So be very careful when switching from SQLite to MySQL in Django project!** You will meet with a lot of bugs like this.